# Assembly bootloader does not load

Tags: assembly, bootloader, gnu-assembler, low-level

I am trying to make an assembly bootloader (AT&T syntax).
I tried to make it load disk sectors into memory and jump to the loaded instructions (using int 13h).
The problem is when my program executes on a VM it doesn't throw an error code, but the AL register (which returns the number of sectors read) contains 0, so I am assuming the sectors are not being read so something must be wrong in my code...
Here is my code:

```
.code16
.text               #executable code location
     .globl _start;
_start:
    jmp _boot
    Fail: .asciz "Failed! Error code - "
    newline: .asciz "\n\r"
    Success: .asciz "Loaded sectors!"
    Read: .asciz "Read "
    sectors: .asciz " sectors!"
    ErrorCode: .byte 0x0
    BootDrive: .byte 0x0
    SectorsRead: .byte 0x0
    .macro WriteSTR str
        leaw \str, %si
        call .PrintSTRIn
    .endm
    .PrintSTRIn:
        lodsb
        orb %al, %al;
        jz .PrintSTROut;
        movb $0x0e, %ah;
        int $0x10;
        call .PrintSTRIn;
    .PrintSTROut:
        ret
_boot:
    xorw %ax, %ax
    movw %ax, %ds
    movw %ax, %es
    movb %dl, (BootDrive)
    movb $0x0, %ah
    int $0x13
    movb $0x02, %ah
    movb $0x01, %al
    movb $0x00, %ch
    movb $0x00, %dh
    movb $0x02, %cl
    movw 0x1000, %ax
    movw %ax, %es
    xorw %bx, %bx
    int $0x13
    movb %al, (SectorsRead)
    movb %ah, (ErrorCode)
    jnc S
    F:
    WriteSTR Fail
    movb (ErrorCode), %al
    addb $48, %al
    movb $0x0e, %ah
    int $0x10
    WriteSTR newline
    jmp .
    S:
    WriteSTR Read
    movb (SectorsRead), %al
    addb $48, %al
    movb $0x0e, %ah
    int $0x10
    WriteSTR sectors
    WriteSTR newline
    jmp $0x1000, $0x0
    . = _start+510
    .byte 0x55
    .byte 0xaa
    WriteSTR Success
    . = _start+2048
```

Help will be appreciated.
BTW I am new to assembly, so sorry if my code is bad :)

Comment: You realize you overwrite `ah` and `al` when you set `ax` to `0x1000`, right? Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: How do you assemble and link this?

Comment: I can't use a debugger because the code is 16 bit, it doesn't run on my Ubuntu machine, that's why I use a VM... also, I am assembling with the built in as command and no special parameters, and link with "ld -Ttext 0x7c00 --oformat=binary <FILENAME>"

Comment: I think that was the problem, thanks! but now for some reason the program goes into an infinite loop or something and stops mid execution (at the instruction "int $0x13"), no error, nothing.

Comment: Do you really expect stack overflow readers to debug it for you, because you can't use a debugger? Find a VM with debugging capabilities (like BOCHS), or switch to 32/64 bit environment, with debugger. (also most of the knowledge you will learn while trying to fix bootloader is pretty much relevant only to the 16 bit bootloader programming = absolutely obsolete and pointless, while learning 32/64b x86 assembly in ordinary user-land programming will bring lot more often insight which can be applied even later in programming modern systems).

Comment: For example you don't reset the `cs` at beginning, so you will be susceptible to BIOS-es which don't jump into bootloader by using `0000:7C00`, but `07C0:0000` (or other alias) ... and there's another ton of similar culprits which you have to know when you are working on real bootloader, but that knowledge is not good for anything else. While learning normal asm programming is much less finicky and actually like half of stuff you will learn are general principles, and can be applied elsewhere...

Comment: I know bootloaders aren't exactly similar to other programs in assembly, but I am trying to write one anyways... and no, I did not expect you to debug for me, I just had no idea that there is a debugging environment for that stuff, so thanks! will try BOCHS.

Comment: Even if you would be unable to get VM with debugger, you can still use dosbox and debug 95% of bootloader code as ordinary DOS COM file, just using few fake bits to ignore some non-bootloader features of such environment and skip some things, but you could still debug + verify most of the bootloader code there before trying VM. Then it will probably still fail due to some tiny detail relevant to bootloading, but at least base code will be already solid and it will require only that specialized BIOS knowledge to work around all the common quirks...

Comment: `movw 0x1000, %ax` you want `movw $0x1000, %ax`

Comment: On other problem is that once you do `jmp $0x1000, $0x0` you'll be running in a different segment with an offset of 0x0000. You'll need to at least set DS to 0x1000. Then you have another problem even if you fix that the function `.PrintSTRIn` is not in the same segment as the bootloader so you'll be trying to call a function at 0x1000:0x7c?? rather than where it was loaded at 0x0000:.PrintSTRIn. Same with the string `success`.

Comment: I recommend reading the second sector into the same segment (0x0000) right after the bootloader at 0x0000:0x7e00 (use BX of 0x7e00 and ES of 0x0000). Then change the JMP to `JMP $0x0000,0x7e00`

Comment: And then in your second sector code after you print `success` you will want to put the bootloader in an infinite loops so it doesn't wander through memory.So after printing `success` do a `jmp .`

Comment: @MichaelPetch, thank you, this solved my problem! Sorry for the noob-ines.